# how to find the command used for a slurm job based on job id?

Tags: slurm

After submitting a slurm job using sbatch file.slurm, you get a job ID. You can use squeue and sacct to check the job's status. But neither returns the original submission command (sbatch file.slurm) for the job. Is there a command to show the submission command, namely sbatch file.slurm? I need to link job IDs with my submission commands.

So far, the only way is by saving the return of sbatch command somewhere.

Comment: Take a look at `scontrol show job`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no command to show the submission command. One workaround is to put the jobname as the filename.

```
#SBATCH -J "file_name"
```

So, when you do `squeue` or `scontrol show job`, then you can match your job id with the filename.

There is no other way to achieve the desired objective.